# ClickOnce problem with not updated version 1.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, clickonce

we are building c# windows apps, using ClickOnce for updates, but some of our clients experience problems with a not updated version, the app runs with version 1.0.0.0 (which not updating). Reinstalling the apps solves the problem, but it is more elimination of consequences.

Maybe some of you already encountered this problem and know how to fix it, or know the possible source of the problem?

Comment: The version number used to determine whether a ClickOnce app should be updated is not the same as the `AssemblyVersion` or `AssemblyFileVersion` version in AssemblyInfo.cs - the version to use is called `ApplicationVersion` in the project file. Are you setting that correctly?

Comment: this situation occurs on workstations, for example, the user has version 1.1.0.263 installed, and the next day when the user runs the app it runs with version 1.0.0.0. No new releases were made. It may be some OS issues?